# Reference a dynamic cell in a formula (in a pivot table)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot, pivot-table, cell

I am trying to reference a cell value in a pivot table as part of a formula outside the table.
This table expands and shrinks.

How do I reference the same cell in a pivot table that is not static?

Thank you.

Comment: You can't unless there is another column in that table that has a unique value that allows Excel to find the correct row, but we cannot help without seeing the data and its format.

Comment: There is. I could reference by using an offset function, and then a vlookup to look for this unique value in the other column. Is this the right approach? Excel doesn't deal well with nested functions, vlookup inside of offset. any ideas:)? @ScottCraner

Comment: Not without seeing some test data and expected outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use GETPIVOTDATA formula as describe in this link https://support.office.com/en-us/article/GETPIVOTDATA-function-8c083b99-a922-4ca0-af5e-3af55960761f. It allows you to reference the pivot table and locate the data using the field names